# Facebook Javascript API call to me/invitable_friends returns only 25 results on cordova but not on web

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a game on cordova that uses facebook integration.  I have a facebook game canvas running on a secure site.

The friend request works fine on the web site version (returns more than 25 results, as I'm iterating the paging.next url that is also returned).

However, on the cordova build (android) it only ever returns the first result set of 25.  It does still have the page.next url JSON field but it just returns a response object with a type=website.

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Same problem using Adobe AIR + webview OAuth. Have you solved it somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know that you call their api from cordova vs website, so it's some problem on your side, maybe you use some different implementation of the api on corodva and website, so that cordova sends a pagination request or send to other api version which does pagination.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of digging I found an issue with the way requests are handled in the FacebookLib for Android.  The current version of the com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect plugin uses Android FacebookSDK 3.21.1 so I'm not sure if this will still be an issue with v4.

A graph result with a paging url is used to request the next page however using the entire url, which includes the https://graph.facebook.com/ as well as the usual graphAction causes an incorrect result set to be returned.  However I determined that if you remove the schema and host parts it will be correct.

I modified the ConnectPlugin.java to check that any schema and host is removed from the graphAction.  Seems to work well now.

ConnectPlugin.java before:

```
private void makeGraphCall()  {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    Request.Callback graphCallback = new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if (graphContext != null) {
                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    graphContext.error(getFacebookRequestErrorResponse(response.getError()));
                } else {
                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();

                    JSONObject innerObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                    graphContext.success(innerObject);
                }
                graphPath = null;
                graphContext = null;
            }
        }
    };

    //If you're using the paging URLs they will be URLEncoded, let's decode them.
    try {
        graphPath = URLDecoder.decode(graphPath, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] urlParts = graphPath.split("\\?");
    String graphAction = urlParts[0];
    Request graphRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(null, graphAction, graphCallback);
    Bundle params = graphRequest.getParameters();

    if (urlParts.length > 1) {
        String[] queries = urlParts[1].split("&");

        for (String query : queries) {
            int splitPoint = query.indexOf("=");
            if (splitPoint > 0) {
                String key = query.substring(0, splitPoint);
                String value = query.substring(splitPoint + 1, query.length());
                params.putString(key, value);

                if (key.equals("access_token")) {
                    if (value.equals(session.getAccessToken())) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "access_token URL: " + value);
                        Log.d(TAG, "access_token SESSION: " + session.getAccessToken());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    params.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());

    graphRequest.setParameters(params);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
}
```

ConnectPlugin.java after:

```
private void makeGraphCall()  {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    Request.Callback graphCallback = new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if (graphContext != null) {
                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    graphContext.error(getFacebookRequestErrorResponse(response.getError()));
                } else {
                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();

                    JSONObject innerObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                    graphContext.success(innerObject);
                }
                graphPath = null;
                graphContext = null;
            }
        }
    };

    //If you're using the paging URLs they will be URLEncoded, let's decode them.
    try {
        graphPath = URLDecoder.decode(graphPath, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] urlParts = graphPath.split("\\?");
    String graphAction = urlParts[0];

    ///////////////////////
    // SECTION ADDED
    ///////////////////////
    final String GRAPH_BASE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
    if(graphAction.indexOf(GRAPH_BASE_URL)==0) {
        URL graphUrl = null;
        try {
            graphUrl = new URL(graphAction);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        graphAction = graphUrl.getPath();
    }
    ///////////////////////
    // END SECTION ADDED
    ///////////////////////

    Request graphRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(null, graphAction, graphCallback);
    Bundle params = graphRequest.getParameters();

    if (urlParts.length > 1) {
        String[] queries = urlParts[1].split("&");

        for (String query : queries) {
            int splitPoint = query.indexOf("=");
            if (splitPoint > 0) {
                String key = query.substring(0, splitPoint);
                String value = query.substring(splitPoint + 1, query.length());
                params.putString(key, value);

                if (key.equals("access_token")) {
                    if (value.equals(session.getAccessToken())) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "access_token URL: " + value);
                        Log.d(TAG, "access_token SESSION: " + session.getAccessToken());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    params.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());

    graphRequest.setParameters(params);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
}
```